# Supremum of the integral over the compact and convex set belongs the extreme set

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T:X \to X$ be a continuous function on a compact metric space. We say that $\mu$ is $T-$invariant if $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathbb{B}_{X}$. We denote by $M(X,T)$ the space of all $T-$invariant measure which is a nonempty, compact and convex in weak* topology. Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Denote $G(f)=\sup_{\mu \in M(X,T)} \int f d\mu$.

$\textbf{Question}:$ Why the supremum is always attained by a measure that belongs to the extreme set $M(X,T)$?

My attempt: I think that is related to the fact $M(X,T)$ is compact and convex in weak* topology, but I don't know why the measure must belong the extreme set $M(X,T)$?

Comment: What do you know about extreme sets? Have you tried using the definition?

Comment: @supinf : Let $\mu=\lambda \mu_{1}+(1-\lambda)\mu_{2}.$ Take integral $\int f \mu= \lambda \int f d\mu_{1}+(1-\lambda)\int f\mu_{2}$, and then take supremum over $M(X,T)$. I don't know what I can get now.

Comment: @supinf : regarding extreme sets, I know a couple of theorems and definitions. I feel I should use Krein–Milman, but I don't know where I missed it. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are right about the compactness.
A continuous function over a (nonempty) compact set always obtains a maximum and a minimum.
In this case, the set is compact in the weak-$*$ topology,
and the function
$$
 h:C(X)\to\Bbb R,\qquad f\mapsto \int f\,\mathrm d\mu
$$
is continuous in the weak-$*$ topology, so this fits together.

A **hint** for the extremal set:

Consider the subset of $M(X,T)$ where the maximum is obtained.
This subset is again weak-$*$ compact and convex.
Pick an extremal point of this subset
(here you have to use Krein-Milman, to argue that such an extremal point exists).
This should also be an extremal point of $M(X,T)$.

Comment: the extremal point is the maximum one? If so, why?

Comment: @Adam not sure I understand the question. Which extremal point do you mean? Have you calculated its function value?